# Norm form for line bundles on double cover

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry

Let $\pi:Y\rightarrow X$ be an unramified double cover of smooth complex projective varieties given by $\eta\in {\rm Pic}(X)$.
In this [paper](https://webusers.imj-prg.fr/%7Eclaire.voisin/Articlesweb/surlajacintdoublesolid.pdf) (1.5 for example), for any line bundle $L\in {\rm Pic}(Y)$, a quadratic form  $q_L:\pi_*L\rightarrow Nm(L)$, where $Nm(L)=det(\pi_*L)\otimes \eta$ induced by the norm map.
We have $\pi_*\mathcal O_Y\simeq \mathcal O_X\oplus \eta$ and $Nm(\mathcal O_Y)\simeq \mathcal O_X$. Locally, the form $q_{\mathcal O_Y}$ should be $\pi^{-1}(U)\rightarrow \pi^{-1}(U)^{\langle 1,\tau\rangle }\simeq \mathcal O_X(U)$, $a\mapsto a\tau(a)$ where $\tau\in Aut_X(Y)$ is the covering involution and $\pi^{-1}(U)^{\langle 1,\tau\rangle }$ the corresponding ring of invariants.

Is there an explicit ($\eta$ has no section) description of $q_{\mathcal O_Y}$ or (which is the same) the bilinear form ${\rm Sym}^2(\pi_*\mathcal O_Y)\simeq \mathcal O_X\oplus\eta\oplus\underbrace{\eta^2}_{\mathcal O_X}\rightarrow Nm(\mathcal O_Y)\simeq \mathcal O_X$ ?

Comment: $q_{\mathscr{O}}$ is simply the composition of the multiplication map $\pi _*\mathscr{O}_Y\otimes \pi _*\mathscr{O}_Y\rightarrow \pi _*\mathscr{O}_Y$ and the trace map $\operatorname{Tr}: \pi _*\mathscr{O}_Y\rightarrow \mathscr{O}_X$. Since $\operatorname{Tr} $ is simply the projection $\mathscr{O}_X\oplus \eta \rightarrow \mathscr{O}_X$, $\ q_{\mathscr{O}}$ kills $\eta $ and induces the isomorphisms $\mathscr{O}_X \rightarrow
\mathscr{O}_X$ and $\eta ^2 \rightarrow\mathscr{O}_X$.

Comment: Thank you very muc for your answer. So in the above decomposition of $\pi_*\mathcal O_Y$, it $(a,b)\mapsto a^2+b^2$. Is it the same for other lines bundles $L$ i.e. $q_L$ is induced by the identity $\pi_*\mathcal L\otimes \pi_*\tau^*L\rightarrow \pi_*(L\times\tau^*L)$ (followed by ${\rm Tr}:\pi_*(L\times\tau^*L)\rightarrow Nm(L)\simeq (\pi_*(L\times\tau^*L))^{\tau}$?

Comment: Yes (except that your $\times$ should be a $\otimes$).

Comment: Thank you again. Maybe your first post could be posted as an answer.